# Welcome message for new chat users

Tags: feature-request, chat

Here in the JS room, we have a nice little script on the bot that display's a welcome message to new user's of the room. However, it gets slightly annoying to the regular's of the room to watch all of those messages.

[image]

Therefore, we would like to have a per-room welcome message feature that gives room's the ability to write a message all new user's of the room, but show's it just to them.

Comment: The [C++ room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) has a [FAQ](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/owners%3Anewbie-hints), which is prominently linked and pinned in the sidebar.

Comment: Isn't this what the pinboard/room topic is for?